# Why does the predicted trend line from a gamm not match the fitted values generated by the same model?

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I am using a GAMM to ask whether the first date of flowering for several plant species is occurring earlier or later over the past ~40 years (potentially due to climate change).  I have separate models for each species.  I use identical code in each case (save the autocorrelation structure, which is specific to each time series).  I am only encountering the following issue for one species.

In the following figure, you'll see my raw data, the fitted values from my model, and the predicted trend line.  You can see that the shape of the predicted trend line is a good fit, but the intercept seems off - the entire trend line is approximately 13 days too high.

[image]

I'm not sure what's going on?  As I said before, I don't encounter this same discrepancy for any of the other species that I've analyzed data for using the same code.  Thank you in advance for any advice you can provide!

My data:

```
first_Ef2<-structure(list(Plot = structure(c(17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L), .Label = c("AF8", "AF9", "EM1", "EM2", "GH1", "GH2", "GH3", "GH4", "GH5", "INT1", "INT2", "INT3", "INT4", "INT5", "MDW", "RM1", "RM2", "RM3", "RM4", "RM5", "RM6", "RM7", "STR", "VR1", "VR2", "WM1", "WM2", "WM3", "WM4", "WM5"), class = "factor"), Year = c(1973, 1973, 1973, 1973, 1973, 1974, 1974, 1974, 1974, 1974, 1975, 1975, 1975, 1975, 1975, 1976, 1976, 1976, 1976, 1976, 1977, 1977, 1977, 1977, 1977, 1978, 1978, 1978, 1978, 1978, 1979, 1979, 1979, 1979, 1979, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1981, 1982, 1982, 1982, 1982, 1982, 1983, 1983, 1983, 1983, 1983, 1984, 1984, 1984, 1984, 1984, 1985, 1985, 1985, 1985, 1985, 1986, 1986, 1986, 1986, 1986, 1987, 1987, 1987, 1987, 1987, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1989, 1989, 1989, 1989, 1989, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1993, 1993, 1993, 1993, 1993, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1994, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1996, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1997, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 1999, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016), DOF = c(NA, NA, NA, 184L, 228L, NA, NA, NA, 233L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 198L, 188L, NA, NA, NA, 181L, 181L, NA, NA, NA, 181L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 195L, 192L, NA, NA, NA, 208L, 173L, NA, NA, NA, 192L, 181L, NA, NA, NA, 193L, 193L, NA, NA, NA, 197L, 188L, NA, NA, NA, 180L, 178L, NA, NA, NA, 179L, 175L, NA, NA, NA, 175L, 173L, NA, NA, NA, 173L, 177L, NA, NA, NA, 176L, 180L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 185L, 187L, NA, NA, NA, 176L, 167L, NA, NA, NA, 193L, 188L, NA, NA, NA, 176L, 176L, NA, NA, NA, 211L, 205L, NA, NA, NA, 186L, 178L, NA, NA, NA, 184L, 184L, NA, NA, NA, 181L, 179L, NA, NA, NA, 186L, 186L, NA, NA, NA, 173L, 164L, NA, NA, NA, 168L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 162L, 158L, NA, NA, NA, 176L, 174L, NA, NA, NA, 164L, 160L, NA, NA, NA, 184L, 182L, NA, NA, NA, 164L, 162L, NA, NA, NA, 166L, 168L, NA, NA, NA, 184L, 178L, NA, 188L, NA, 180L, 180L, NA, NA, NA, 176L, 184L, NA, NA, NA, 192L, 198L, NA, NA, NA, 156L, 156L, NA, NA, 176L, 174L, 166L, NA, NA, 230L, 184L, 180L, 182L, 180L, 178L, 172L, 170L, NA, 256L, 178L, 178L, 174L)), .Names = c("Plot", "Year", "DOF"), row.names = c(5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 10L, 8L, 9L, 6L, 7L, 15L, 13L, 14L, 11L, 12L, 20L, 18L, 19L, 16L, 17L, 25L, 23L, 24L, 21L, 22L, 210L, 208L, 209L, 206L, 207L, 30L, 28L, 29L, 26L, 27L, 35L, 33L, 34L, 31L, 32L, 40L, 38L, 39L, 36L, 37L, 45L, 43L, 44L, 41L, 42L, 50L, 48L, 49L, 46L, 47L, 55L, 53L, 54L, 51L, 52L, 60L, 58L, 59L, 56L, 57L, 65L, 63L, 64L, 61L, 62L, 70L, 68L, 69L, 66L, 67L, 75L, 73L, 74L, 71L, 72L, 215L, 213L, 214L, 211L, 212L, 80L, 78L, 79L, 76L, 77L, 85L, 83L, 84L, 81L, 82L, 90L, 88L, 89L, 86L, 87L, 95L, 93L, 94L, 91L, 92L, 100L, 98L, 99L, 96L, 97L, 105L, 103L, 104L, 101L, 102L, 110L, 108L, 109L, 106L, 107L, 115L, 113L, 114L, 111L, 112L, 120L, 118L, 119L, 116L, 117L, 125L, 123L, 124L, 121L, 122L, 130L, 128L, 129L, 126L, 127L, 135L, 133L, 134L, 131L, 132L, 140L, 138L, 139L, 136L, 137L, 145L, 143L, 144L, 141L, 142L, 150L, 148L, 149L, 146L, 147L, 155L, 153L, 154L, 151L, 152L, 160L, 158L, 159L, 156L, 157L, 165L, 163L, 164L, 161L, 162L, 170L, 168L, 169L, 166L, 167L, 175L, 173L, 174L, 171L, 172L, 180L, 178L, 179L, 176L, 177L, 185L, 183L, 184L, 181L, 182L, 190L, 188L, 189L, 186L, 187L, 195L, 193L, 194L, 191L, 192L, 200L, 198L, 199L, 196L, 197L, 205L, 203L, 204L, 201L, 202L), class = "data.frame")
```

My model:

```
library(mcgv)

Ef_mod2<-gamm(DOF~s(Year, k=-1, fx=T), random=list(Plot=~1), correlation=corARMA(form=~Year, p=2, q=2), method="REML", data=first_Ef, na.action=na.exclude, control=list(maxIter=2000, msMaxIter=2000))

#Sequence of years over which I want to examine the fitted values and trend line
pdat<-with(first_Ef, data.frame(Year=seq(min(Year), max(Year), length=42)))

#Plot of raw data
plot(first_Ef$Year, first_Ef$DOF, ylab="Ordinal date of flowering", xlab="Year")

#Add fitted values
points(fitted(Ef_mod2$lme)~first_Ef$Year[which(first_Ef$DOF!="NA")], col='red')

#Add predicted trend line and confidence intervals
fit<-predict(Ef_mod2$gam, newdata=pdat, type="response", se=T)$fit

se<-predict(Ef_mod2$gam, newdata=pdat, type="response", se=T)$se.fit

lines(fit~pdat$Year, lwd=2)

lines(fit-1.96*se~pdat$Year, lwd=2, lty=2, col='darkgrey')

lines(fit+1.96*se~pdat$Year, lwd=2, lty=2, col='darkgrey')

legend('bottomleft', pch=c(21, 21, 19), col=c('black', 'red', 'black'), legend=c("raw data", "fitted values", "annual averages"), bty='n')
```

*Please note that this model was the one that yielded the lowest AIC value despite not completely resolving autocorrelation issues.

Comment: You should add the intercept to the fitted values you get from the predict function.